# Serial Port Data to txt File then continuously amend txt File to 2 lines. issues

Tags: bash, command-line, serial-port

### **Here is what I have.** which works..... but

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n > ~/sites/received.txt

while :
do
(stty raw; cat > ~/sites/received.txt | tail -n 2 ~/sites/received.txt > ~/sites/received.txt) < /dev/cu.usbmodem1431
done
```

---

the file gets bigger every 10 seconds or so... Its like there is data leakage.  The received.txt file never stays to only 2 lines.

Is there a better way to temporarily hold serial data in a txt file?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach can't work for several reasons, primarily because `cat` reads the input until end-of-file is reached (which won't happen with `stty raw`).

To just store the two most recent input lines in the file, do in your loop

```
line2="$line"; read line </dev/cu.usbmodem1431; { echo $line2; echo $line; } >received.txt
```